# Use geospatial data type as input for Apache Beam

Tags: python-2.7, gis, apache-beam

Is it possible to read from a geospatial data source (e.g. Shapefile, Geopackage) using Apache Beam's Python SDK?

I found [this](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.6.0/apache_beam.io.filebasedsource.html?highlight=_avrosource) page but don't know how to take it from there.

Comment: You may need to use an intermediate format to send/receive geospatial data

Comment: Did you go anywhere with this?

Comment: unfortunately not.